# The length of chord which is at distance of 10 cm from the center of the circle having radius 20 cm

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Diagram to finding chord  in easy way

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Could you share with us some of your own thoughts?

Comment: What does this have to do with _Ramanujan summation_, of all things?

Answer (score 4):

Draw the circle, and the chord, and the radii from the ends of the chord and the perpendicular bisector of the chord. There are right triangles. Solve them. Add.